# JAXB Java and XSD mapping

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

In one of my projects I use JAXB2 marshaller, having a contract-first web service I generate the objects from a XML Schema.

Everything works just fine. But, I have a "code usability" issue. Let me give you an example.

Schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="personContractAlertListType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="PersonContractAlert" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="PersonContractAlertsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="PersonContractAlertList"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So in order to access the list of `PersonContractAlerts` I have to call:

```
PersonContractAlertsResponse.getPersonContractAlertListType().getPersonContractAlert()
```

Which is kinda long.

My question is: How can I get rid of the `getPersonContractAlertListType()` and go directly to: `PersonContractAlertsResponse.getPersonContractAlert()`

Because that wrapper element is really only for XSD, I don't need it in my Java object.

In other words have:

```
<Element1>
<Wrapper>
<Element2/>
</Wrapper>
</Element1>
```

And I want it in Java to map to: `Element1.getElement2()`

Maybe using JAXB adaptors. And remember I don't want to touch generated objects. This has to be done either in the marshaller settings (adaptar, interceptor, etc) or in the XSD (maybe there are some settings to manipulate).

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

I found a tutorial on some binding operations:

https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html

I will research try using JAXB bindings.

Comment: That link is now https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the object model you want, you could use the XPath based mapping extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: But the question was if I can do that without changing the generated class.

Comment: To go between the XML and object you want you'll need an XmlAdapter and an customization to make use of it.  Changing your model may be cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about your particular situation, but in general, typing an extra 30 characters is probably not a big enough cost to justify even searching for a solution to this.  Especially since Eclipse will auto-complete that method call.